# VSCode Webview with iframe - unable to look into iframe dom for Webview Dev Tools

Tags: iframe, visual-studio-code, webview

I am building a VSCode Webview that exposes a more complex tool for usage in VSCode....

So...  See below for example

This code works fine for starting up the Builder tool.   BUT, I have a bug somewhere in that tool in the VSCode environment (maybe file access issue)...

So, I opened the Webview Developer Tools - and can do the usual look at the elements, etc...  BUT when I get to the iframe (with html provided from the iframe src Builder), I cant look into that iframe, cant debug anything in it..     Normally in Google dev tools, I can walk into nested iframes just fine.  I get no error or other indication.   The display in the WebView clearly has significant UI, but no way to debug it that I have found....

Any help is appreciated.

```
private getWebViewContent(webview: vscode.Webview): string {
    const initialHTML = `<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>LBF EMail Builder</title>
        <style>
            html { width: 100%; height: 100%; min-height: 100%; display: flex; }
            body { flex: 1; display: flex; }
            iframe { flex: 1; border: none; background: white; }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <iframe id="lbfemailbuilder" src="http://localhost:3000"></iframe>
    </body>
    `;
    return initialHTML;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to ask the dev team to reopen this issue:

https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/105370#issuecomment-717157594